# Xmonad windows flashing on other workspaces

Tags: 14.04, workspaces, window, xmonad

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. I use Xmonad. I am an experiencing an odd behavior where windows will flash through onto other workspaces. I can only remove the appearance of erroneous windows by repositioning the windows on the current workspace. This is especially problematic when I attempt to run fullscreen floating borderless windows, which is how I run Dota 2.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is an issue with Chrome - see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370022.

The quick fix is using xcompmgr to enable compositing, e.g. by adding `xcompmgr -a &` to your .Xsession (or similar session initialization script).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I use Ubuntu's login manager to start xmonad, so I'm not sure where I would add such a command.